# How to save or export a custom Linux kernel configuration?

Tags: linux, kernel

I downloaded a Linux Kernel from [www.kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org), then I used menuconfig to customize it.

After a lot of customizing it works just like I need it to, and I don't want to loose this actual configuration, so I could later (in another machine, by example) download the same kernel version, and use my configuration. How could I do that?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899104/how-to-create-a-defconfig-file-from-a-config

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just copy `.config` file from source directory. This file contains your current configuration.

Also when updating sources you can do `make oldconfig` to preserve old changes and only decide what to do with new stuff, it will only ask about new configuration options (updates current configuration). You still need to move in your old `.config` file before you can use this.

Comment: and also archive the .config's in github?

Answer (score 10):

One option is:

```
make savedefconfig
```

which will create a file named `defconfig` in your current directory. You can now copy this file to `arch/<architecture>/configs/my_defconfig` (take care that the file name has to end with `_defconfig`), e.g.:

```
cp defconfig arch/x86/configs/my_defconfig
```

When you've done this you can type the following to generate the `.config` from your configuration (for the provided architecture):

```
export ARCH=x86
make my_defconfig
```

I think this is preferred way to store kernel configurations and once it is set up it is easier to maintain since you can easily switch from one configuration to another.

Comment: One advantage of `make savedefconfig` is that is minimizes the generated `defconfig`: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/scripts/kconfig/confdata.c#L665 skipping redundant configs that are implied by others.

Answer (score 4):

You can either save the config file to a custom location directly in menuconfig and load a custom one there as well or you can save the .config file from the kernel source location eg `/usr/src/linux/.config`

To save directly in menuconfig scroll down to the last two options `Load / Save an Alternate Configuration File`

Answer (score 1):

into Kenrel Source Directory copy ".config" and replace in to destination directory.